# How make PDF Viewer for winforms C#

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, activex, ocx

Any PDF Libray or OCX for Read PDf Files and show winform. I dont want user ActiveX Acrobat because i need install Acrobat Reader.

I need to hide save and print buttons too. Will open PDF encrypted.

I really liked Foxit SDK ActiveX  more very expansive $3000usd. Apitron is free but it LOSS OF RESOLUTION WHEN OPENING PDF. (i already set it for renderingQuality = high)

Someone know ?

Comment: https://www.verydoc.com/pdf-viewer-ocx.html
?
But maybe AcrobatReader ActiveX ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the Document Viewer from the LEADTOOLS Nuget here:

WPF Viewer: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Document.Viewer.Wpf/

WinForms Viewer: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Document.Viewer.WinForms/

Just as a disclaimer, I am an employee of this vendor.

It supports viewing PDFs and other document and image formats as document or image. This works without any installations or running ActiveX components.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate PDF Viewer controls for WinForms/WPF by DevExpress. You can easily customize these controls as your needs dictate.

- [PDF Viewer for WinForms](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/pdf-viewer/)
- [PDF Viewer for WPF](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/pdf_viewer/)